# Supersized thumb-tray plus thumb-table

Tags: php, jquery, css, joomla, supersized

I am using the Supersized module in Joomla. At the moment, I have an article in the center of the page. If I close the article, I see the Supersized Gallery and the thumb-tray, which allows me to open each photo as a background, as I click on the thumbnails.

I would like to put a table in the article, with the same thumbnails as in the tray. This way, if a user wants, he could click the thumbnails from the article and see the background change.

If I tried to write, in the article, the following code:

```
    <div id="thumb-tray" class="load-item hide_function hidden-phone">
        <div id="thumb-back"></div>
        <div id="thumb-forward"></div>
      </div>
```

I would not get anything, and the Supersized gallery would not even work...
Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this problem?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: do you have an URL or a JSfiddle? That would allow a much wider audience to try solve your issue

Comment: a sample of the Supersized Gallery can be found [here](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html). My goal is making the same clickable thumbnails that appear in the tray at the bottom of the page, available in the center of the page. @skv

Comment: kindly show us what you tried, without which it is very difficult to understand the issue

Comment: @skv the site I'm working on, is not online yet. I can't upload it right now.I just don't know what to put in the article, for it to show the same thumbnails as the thumb-tray... Thanks for your comprehension.

Comment: Please consider jsfiddle.com thats useful to demonstrate your issue

Comment: As you know, jsfiddle is only for JavaScript; in this case, obviously, there is the need of PHP and Joomla, so it is not possible to use jsfiddle, for my needs. If you can help, please suggest something. I have written everything I could, to explain my problem... @skv

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at joomla.stackexchange.com).